# How to create 3x3 grid menu in react native without 3rd party lib?

Tags: css, react-native, grid-layout

I want to create grid center menu in react native, I just read [the doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#align-items) and looks good to start, but I have a problem to creating line for each grid menu

I've created 3x3 grid flexbox with Copy-Paste the code :

```
<View style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
        <View>
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
          <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:10, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        </View>
      </View>
```

and the result looks like :

[image]

but I need to add a line for each menu and my goal is to create a menu grid like :

[image]

I have done collecting the icon for each menu, and will be replacing the view with my `Icon + Text`

Anyone can help me how to create menu like above?

Comment: the problem is that you don't have the grey line ?

Comment: @CladClad yes, that's true, the problem is how to set grey line like images above?

Comment: the line will just be a trick with the marginLeft and bottom and a grey background ;)

Answer (score 3):

I change the last color to be more visible and made the line "grey" (you can use lightgrey or any custom color you want) so that you can change it easily.

```
import {Dimensions, View} from 'react-native'    
const DeviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
```

Here is the code inside the render function:

```
  <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}>
    <View style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: "grey"}}>
      <View>
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:1, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:1, marginLeft:1, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:1, marginLeft:1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginLeft:1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:1, marginLeft:1, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginBottom:1, marginLeft:1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: DeviceWidth*0.2, height: DeviceWidth*0.2, marginLeft:1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}} />
      </View>    
    </View>
  </View>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: have you tried this before? I just try your code and its looks strange

Comment: I tried it and it works for me, I just added a picture to show you

Comment: How to change the color of the margins?